# Article with Code snippet in Laravel & vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, blogs, code-snippets

Any ideas on how to create blog posts and within the article the user can include code snippets, but these code snippets are only to be viewed.
when I try to parse the article's body in the blade template it throws an error that the variables in the code snippet are not defined.
thanks

I want to upload this code snippet

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  @foreach($articles as $a)         
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a href="/articles/{{$a->id}}" class="text-dark font-weight-bold">{{$a->title}}</a>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

and I get this in the console

```
app.js:79994 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token '>' in
```

Answer (score 0):

use `htmlspecialchars($request->body)` when you save to database.

use `{!! htmlspecialchars_decode($post->body) !!}` in blade

Comment: the problem is when the user uploads laravel blade code snippet, it is executed,